# I used openssl model to decrypt ciphertext,but sometimes php server can return decrypted ciphertext, sometimes return null

Tags: php, ios, openssl, rsa

I used openssl model to decrypt ciphertext,but sometimes php server can return decrypted ciphertext, sometimes return null

in objective-c
CRSA.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

typedef enum {
    KeyTypePublic,
    KeyTypePrivate
}KeyType;

typedef enum {
    RSA_PADDING_TYPE_NONE       = RSA_NO_PADDING,
    RSA_PADDING_TYPE_PKCS1      = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
    RSA_PADDING_TYPE_SSLV23     = RSA_SSLV23_PADDING
}RSA_PADDING_TYPE;

@interface CRSA : NSObject{
    RSA *_rsa;
}
+ (id)shareInstance;
- (BOOL)importRSAKeyWithType:(KeyType)type;
- (int)getBlockSizeWithRSA_PADDING_TYPE:(RSA_PADDING_TYPE)padding_type;
- (NSString *) encryptByRsa:(NSString*)content withKeyType:(KeyType)keyType;
- (NSString *) decryptByRsa:(NSString*)content withKeyType:(KeyType)keyType;
@end
```

CRSA.m

```
 #import "CRSA.h"
#define BUFFSIZE  1024
#import "Base64.h"

#define PADDING RSA_PADDING_TYPE_PKCS1
@implementation CRSA

+ (id)shareInstance
{
    static CRSA *_crsa = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _crsa = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _crsa;
}
- (BOOL)importRSAKeyWithType:(KeyType)type
{
    FILE *file;
    NSString *keyName = type == KeyTypePublic ? @"public_key" : @"private_key";
    NSString *keyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:keyName ofType:@"pem"];
    file = fopen([keyPath UTF8String], "rb");

    if (NULL != file)
    {
        if (type == KeyTypePublic)
        {
            _rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            assert(_rsa != NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            _rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            assert(_rsa != NULL);
        }

        fclose(file);

        return (_rsa != NULL) ? YES : NO;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (NSString *) encryptByRsa:(NSString*)content withKeyType:(KeyType)keyType
{
    if (![self importRSAKeyWithType:keyType])
         return nil;

    int status;
    int length  = [content length];
    unsigned char input[length + 1];
    bzero(input, length + 1);
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++)
    {
        input[i] = [content characterAtIndex:i];
    }

    NSInteger  flen = [self getBlockSizeWithRSA_PADDING_TYPE:PADDING];

    char *encData = (char*)malloc(flen);
    bzero(encData, flen);

    switch (keyType) {
        case KeyTypePublic:
            status = RSA_public_encrypt(length, (unsigned char*)input, (unsigned char*)encData, _rsa, PADDING);
            break;

        default:
            status = RSA_private_encrypt(length, (unsigned char*)input, (unsigned char*)encData, _rsa, PADDING);
            break;
    }

    if (status)
    {
        NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithBytes:encData length:status];
        free(encData);
        encData = NULL;

        NSString *ret = [returnData base64EncodedString];
        return ret;
    }

    free(encData);
    encData = NULL;

    return nil;
}

- (NSString *) decryptByRsa:(NSString*)content withKeyType:(KeyType)keyType
{
    if (![self importRSAKeyWithType:keyType])
        return nil;

    int status;

    NSData *data = [content base64DecodedData];
    int length = [data length];

    NSInteger flen = [self getBlockSizeWithRSA_PADDING_TYPE:PADDING];
    char *decData = (char*)malloc(flen);
    bzero(decData, flen);

    switch (keyType) {
        case KeyTypePublic:
            status = RSA_public_decrypt(length, (unsigned char*)[data bytes], (unsigned char*)decData, _rsa, PADDING);
            break;

        default:
            status = RSA_private_decrypt(length, (unsigned char*)[data bytes], (unsigned char*)decData, _rsa, PADDING);
            break;
    }

    if (status)
    {
        NSMutableString *decryptString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:decData length:strlen(decData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        free(decData);
        decData = NULL;

        return decryptString;
    }

    free(decData);
    decData = NULL;

    return nil;
}

- (int)getBlockSizeWithRSA_PADDING_TYPE:(RSA_PADDING_TYPE)padding_type
{
    int len = RSA_size(_rsa);

    if (padding_type == RSA_PADDING_TYPE_PKCS1 || padding_type == RSA_PADDING_TYPE_SSLV23) {
        len -= 11;
    }

    return len;
}
@end
```

Base64.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSData (Base64)

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:(NSUInteger)wrapWidth;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString;

@end


@interface NSString (Base64)

+ (NSString *)stringWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:(NSUInteger)wrapWidth;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString;
- (NSString *)base64DecodedString;
- (NSData *)base64DecodedData;

@end
```

Base64.m

```
#import "Base64.h"


#import <Availability.h>
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This library requires automatic reference counting
#endif


@implementation NSData (Base64)

+ (NSData *)dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    const char lookup[] =
    {
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 62, 99, 99, 99, 63, 
        52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
        99,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
        99, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
        41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99
    };

    NSData *inputData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    long long inputLength = [inputData length];
    const unsigned char *inputBytes = [inputData bytes];

    long long maxOutputLength = (inputLength / 4 + 1) * 3;
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:maxOutputLength];
    unsigned char *outputBytes = (unsigned char *)[outputData mutableBytes];

    int accumulator = 0;
    long long outputLength = 0;
    unsigned char accumulated[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (long long i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        unsigned char decoded = lookup[inputBytes[i] & 0x7F];
        if (decoded != 99)
        {
            accumulated[accumulator] = decoded;
            if (accumulator == 3)
            {
                outputBytes[outputLength++] = (accumulated[0] << 2) | (accumulated[1] >> 4);  
                outputBytes[outputLength++] = (accumulated[1] << 4) | (accumulated[2] >> 2);  
                outputBytes[outputLength++] = (accumulated[2] << 6) | accumulated[3];
            }
            accumulator = (accumulator + 1) % 4;
        }
    }

    //handle left-over data
    if (accumulator > 0) outputBytes[outputLength] = (accumulated[0] << 2) | (accumulated[1] >> 4);
    if (accumulator > 1) outputBytes[++outputLength] = (accumulated[1] << 4) | (accumulated[2] >> 2);
    if (accumulator > 2) outputLength++;

    //truncate data to match actual output length
    outputData.length = outputLength;
    return outputLength? outputData: nil;
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:(NSUInteger)wrapWidth
{
    //ensure wrapWidth is a multiple of 4
    wrapWidth = (wrapWidth / 4) * 4;

    const char lookup[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    long long inputLength = [self length];
    const unsigned char *inputBytes = [self bytes];

    long long maxOutputLength = (inputLength / 3 + 1) * 4;
    maxOutputLength += wrapWidth? (maxOutputLength / wrapWidth) * 2: 0;
    unsigned char *outputBytes = (unsigned char *)malloc(maxOutputLength);

    long long i;
    long long outputLength = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputLength - 2; i += 3)
    {
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[(inputBytes[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[((inputBytes[i] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inputBytes[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[((inputBytes[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inputBytes[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[inputBytes[i + 2] & 0x3F];

        //add line break
        if (wrapWidth && (outputLength + 2) % (wrapWidth + 2) == 0)
        {
            outputBytes[outputLength++] = '\r';
            outputBytes[outputLength++] = '\n';
        }
    }

    //handle left-over data
    if (i == inputLength - 2)
    {
        // = terminator
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[(inputBytes[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[((inputBytes[i] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inputBytes[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[(inputBytes[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] =   '=';
    }
    else if (i == inputLength - 1)
    {
        // == terminator
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[(inputBytes[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = lookup[(inputBytes[i] & 0x03) << 4];
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = '=';
        outputBytes[outputLength++] = '=';
    }

    if (outputLength >= 4)
    {
        //truncate data to match actual output length
        outputBytes = realloc(outputBytes, outputLength);
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:outputBytes
                                              length:outputLength
                                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                        freeWhenDone:YES];
    }
    else if (outputBytes)
    {
        free(outputBytes);
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    return [self base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0];
}

@end


@implementation NSString (Base64)

+ (NSString *)stringWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:string];
    if (data)
    {
        return [[self alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:(NSUInteger)wrapWidth
{
    NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    return [data base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:wrapWidth];
}

- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    return [data base64EncodedString];
}

- (NSString *)base64DecodedString
{
    return [NSString stringWithBase64EncodedString:self];
}

- (NSData *)base64DecodedData
{
    return [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:self];
}

@end
```

in PHP
api.php

```
<?php

define('IN_ECS', true);

include_once 'Rsa.php';
include_once 'cls_json.php';

parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post);


$json = new JSON;
$rsa = new Rsa;
$result['reply'] = $rsa->privDecrypt($post['text']);
show_json($json, $result, true);

function parse_json(&$json, $str)
{
    if (defined('CHARSET') && CHARSET == 'gbk')
    {
        $str = addslashes(stripslashes(ecs_iconv('utf-8', 'gbk', $str)));
    }
    $json_obj = $json->decode($str, 1);
    $_POST = $json_obj;
}

function show_json(&$json, $array, $convert = false)
{
    $json_str = $json->encode($array, false);
    if (!$convert && defined('CHARSET') && CHARSET == 'gbk')
    {
        $json_str = ecs_iconv('UTF-8', 'GBK', $json_str);
    }
    @header('Content-type:text/html; charset='.CHARSET);
    exit($json_str);
}


?>
```

Rsa.php

```
<?php
class Rsa
{
private static $PRIVATE_KEY = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
(MyPrivateKey)
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF;
    private static function getPrivateKey(){

        $privKey = self::$PRIVATE_KEY;

        return openssl_pkey_get_private($privKey);      
    }
    public static function privEncrypt($data)
    {
        if(!is_string($data)){
                return null;
        }           
        return openssl_private_encrypt($data,$encrypted,self::getPrivateKey())? base64_encode($encrypted) : null;
    }

    public static function privDecrypt($encrypted)
    {
        if(!is_string($encrypted)){
                return null;
        }
        openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, self::getPrivateKey(),OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

    return $decrypted;
        // return (openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, self::getPrivateKey()))? $decrypted : null;
    }
}

?>
```

I send a piece of ciphertext like "test test", and Log the the decrypted ciphertext in Xcode

NSLog

```
2013-10-20 13:54:47.518 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":null}
2013-10-20 13:54:47.700 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":"test test"}
2013-10-20 13:54:47.856 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":null}
2013-10-20 13:54:48.023 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":null}
2013-10-20 13:54:48.185 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":"test test"}
2013-10-20 13:54:48.346 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":null}
2013-10-20 13:54:48.486 test[1197:a0b] {"reply":null}
```

I don't konw the reason, please help me, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it didn't use URL-Safe Encoding